# custom ValidationForMessage helper removing css element

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi have an html helper that allows me to apply a different style to the ValidationForMessage.

My question is how to I tap into the validation event to either change a css element of the message or trigger some javascript?

My code looks like

```
 public static MvcHtmlString ValidationStyledMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex)
    {
        var result = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(ex);
        var res = string.Format("<span class=\"required-field\"></span> <span class=\"error required hidden\"><p>{0}<a class=\"close\" href=\"javascript:closeError();\"></a></p></span>", result.ToHtmlString());
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(res);
    }
```

As you can see I have a span with a class that is hidden. What I would like to happen is whenever the validation message should be shown I remove the hidden css class.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could proceed:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationStyledMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex)
{
    var expression = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(ex);
    var modelName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
    var modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
    var modelErrors = modelState == null ? null : modelState.Errors;
    var modelError = ((modelErrors == null) || (modelErrors.Count == 0)) 
        ? null 
        : modelErrors.FirstOrDefault(m => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.ErrorMessage)) ?? modelErrors[0];
    var result = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(ex);

    if (modelError != null)
    {
        // There was an error => remove the hidden class
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<span class=\"required-field\"></span> <span class=\"error required\"><p>{0}<a class=\"close\" href=\"javascript:closeError();\"></a></p></span>", result.ToHtmlString()));
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<span class=\"required-field\"></span> <span class=\"error required hidden\"><p>{0}<a class=\"close\" href=\"javascript:closeError();\"></a></p></span>", result.ToHtmlString()));
}
```

---

UPDATE:

If you have client side validation enabled you will also need to plug into the jquery validate plugin and manually indicate how to highlight/unhighlight error fields as you have customized the markup. This can be done by simply overriding the default values of the plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).siblings('span.error').addClass('hidden');
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).siblings('span.error').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Darin, I have tried your suggestion and tried debugging to see whats happening but its not working for me, I step through the code and modelState is always null which then causes modelError always to be null.
>  return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<span class=\"required-field\"></span is never been hit?

Comment: @Diver Dan, in my test I've used a view model with a single property decorated with the `[Required]` attribute. Then I put both `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyProperty)` and `@Html.ValidationStyledMessageFor(x => x.MyProperty)`. When the form was first rendered the span had the hidden class but when I submitted it to the POST action by leaving the field empty the validation error was added to the model state and the helper entered the second case and showed the span. What is your test case?

Comment: Yes I am doing the same as you 
>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName) @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName) @Html.ValidationStyledMessageFor(model => model.UserName)</code> for my view and my model looks like 
>public class RegisterModel { [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is required")] [Display(Name = "User name")] public string UserName { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks Darin, sorry I didnt think about mentioning the clientside validation

Comment: @Diver Dan, no problem, it's just that client validation was the culprit here and it took me time to realize this :-)