# Is it possible to make MVC 3 validation render in a div instead of a span

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So rather than spend time trying to make spans that are empty behave in IE 7, is there a quick way to make validation render inside of a div instead of a span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the `Html.ValidationMessageFor` or `Html.ValidationSummary` helpers there is no easy way to modify the markup they are generating other than writing your own custom helpers. I showed [some example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410665/custom-validationformessage-helper-removing-css-element/5412346#5412346).

Comment: DOH!, I figure that was the case. I guess my validation will look crappy in IE7 for now. I don't see spending the time to fix an issue with one browser that is old.

Comment: @CrazyCoderz, who cares about IE7 :-) Leave that crap and spend your time on bringing real value to your application :-)

Comment: Yep, moving on... IE7 can @#$% it :)