# MVC4 Form Input Validation - Customising the error span

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with several inputs using `Html.TextBoxFor` and each input has a `ValidationMessageFor` which gets it's error message from the `ViewModel` attributes. For this example, we'll pretend there's just one input:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Code)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Code)
```

When there's a model error, the validator displays it's error message within a couple of spans which looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Code" id="Code" data-val-required="Personalised code is required" data-val="true" class="input-validation-error">
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Code" class="field-validation-error">
    <span for="Code" generated="true" class="">Personalised code is required</span>
</span>
```

How do I customise this error message?

For example change the outer span to a div and give both the div and span clases?

```
<div class="myOuterSpan" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Code" class="field-validation-error">
    <span class="myInnerSpan" for="Code" generated="true" class="">Personalised code is required</span>
</div>
```

Or just have one span?

```
<span class="errorWrapper" for="Code" generated="true">Code is required</span>
```

Or wrap the whole lot in a div?

```
<div class="myOuterDiv">
    <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Code" class="field-validation-error">
        <span for="Code" generated="true" class="">Personalised code is required</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

You get the idea...

**THE SOLUTION**

I based my solution on Darin's answer and created a CustomValidationMessage, not the customValidationMessageFOR as I was initially intending on creating.

CONTROLLER

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "Invalid Code");
```

VIEW

```
@Html.CustomValidationMessage("Code")
```

EXTENSION

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomValidationMessage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string modelName)
    {
        var modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
        var modelErrors = modelState == null ? null : modelState.Errors;
        var modelError = ((modelErrors == null) || (modelErrors.Count == 0))
            ? null
            : modelErrors.FirstOrDefault(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorMessage)) ?? modelErrors[0];

        if (modelError != null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create("<span class='validation_wrapper customValidation'><span>" + modelError.ErrorMessage +"</span></span>");
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410665/custom-validationformessage-helper-removing-css-element/5412346#5412346)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to modify the markup generated by the `ValidationMessageFor` helper. If you want to do that you will have to write a custom helper. Here's how the signature of this helper might look like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
)
{
    ...
}
```

You might also checkout a [`similar post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5412346/29407).

Comment: You can modify the markup slightly. I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need for a custom extension. For example:

Controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("InvalidLogin", "Your credentials are invalid.")
```

View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor
(
  model => model.InvalidLogin, 
  "", 
  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "text-error" }, 
  tag: "div"
)
```

Comment: Yeah that works if you've only got one validation message, but what if you have several, do you wrap each one in a span?

Comment: Yes. Unless you have some complex markup. However, most of the time a div or a span with a custom class does the trick.